# Filtering for fields in foreign key objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    isprivate = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class View(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    isprivate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name='views')
```

I want to get a QuerySet of all projects that are not private and have at least one View that is not private. E.g., something along the lines of:

```
Project.objects.filter(isprivate=False, views__isprivate=False)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Project.objects.filter(isprivate=False)
               .annotate(private_views=Count('views__isprivate'))
               .filter(private_views__gte=1)
```

Find out more about `Count()` at the [documentation on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: Thank you so much. But this gives me all public projects that have one at least one private view. I want all public projects that have at least one public view. Is there a way to negate the statement in `Count`?